# Sparkfun OBDII - Arduino Uno Stuck at 832RPM-13Kmh

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm working on a hobby project with Sparkfun OBDII UART + Arduino Uno + 16x2 LCD Screen, i'm trying to read my car's RPM-Speed-Coolant Temprature-Oxy Sensor on runtime.

[Product Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJyY9.jpg)

Wired OBDII to Arduino as:
OBD TX -> ARDUINO RX
OBD RX-> ARDUINO TX
OBD GND -> ARDUINO GND

As far as i understand OBDII board does all the job and it's just communicating with arduino through serial, they provided an example here : [Hookup Guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uuamb.jpg)

I don't have sparkfun serial lcd, so i've changed codes according to my lcd as follow;

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include "DFRobot_RGBLCD.h"
const int colorR = 255;
const int colorG = 0;
const int colorB = 0;
DFRobot_RGBLCD lcd(16,2);  //16 characters and 2 lines of show
char rxData[20];
char rxIndex=0;
int vehicleSpeed=0;
int vehicleRPM=0;
void setup()
{
lcd.init();
lcd.setRGB(colorR, colorG, colorB);
Serial.begin(9600);
lcd.clear();  
lcd.setCursor(0,0);
lcd.print("Hiz: ");
lcd.setCursor(0,1);
lcd.print("Devir: ");
delay(1500);
Serial.println("ATZ");
delay(2000);
Serial.flush();
}

void loop()
{
Serial.println("010D");
getResponse();
getResponse();
vehicleSpeed = strtol(&rxData[6],0,16);
lcd.setCursor(4,0);
lcd.print(vehicleSpeed);
lcd.print(" km/h");
delay(100);
Serial.flush();
Serial.println("010C");
getResponse();
getResponse();
vehicleRPM = ((strtol(&rxData[6],0,16)*256)+strtol(&rxData[9],0,16))/4;
lcd.setCursor(6,1);
lcd.print(vehicleRPM);
delay(100);
}
void getResponse(void){
  char inChar=0;
  while(inChar != '\r'){
    if(Serial.available() > 0){
      if(Serial.peek() == '\r'){
        inChar=Serial.read();
        rxData[rxIndex]='\0';
        rxIndex=0;
      }
      else{
        inChar = Serial.read();
        rxData[rxIndex++]=inChar;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

with above code i believe arduino receives last rpm and speed record before i shut down the engine which is 832RPM - 13 Kmh (at this point i'm not sure if arduino receive speed value correctly because when i shut down the engine i was parked the car and speed was 0kmh), in normal case when i start the car rpm and speed value should have changed but even after started the car the value stands still,it's not changing.

I bought waveshare's USB FTDI(TTL) adapter to figure it out is this board communicate with car or pc properly, connected usb ttl as;
OBD TX -> TTL RX
OBD RX-> TTL TX
OBD GND -> TTL GND

connected to OBDII port of my car, opened tera term, connected to COM20 (ttl defined as com20 on the pc) and run below commands as suggested in their manual;

```
ATZ -- resetted card successfully
ATRV -- returned 12.4 V as it should be, which is my battery voltage
ATSP0 -- auto find and select car's protocol it returned OK
010C -- RPM of the car it returned 41 0C 00 00 (engine wasn't started)
010C -- RPM of the car it returned 41 0C 10 F4 (engine started--idle RPM arround 1.000 rpm)
010D -- speed of the car it returned 41 00 00
010D -- speed of the car it returned 41 00 00 both value is the same because the car is not moving :)
```

According to above outcome the board is fine and communicating with car or pc or arduino without any problem.

But when i try with arduino when i connect the board to my car and turn my ignition to battery mode it reads rpm as 832 and speed as 13 and don't update those values even i start the engine.

What am i doing wrong?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after 1 week of try i finally solved it :)

As you guys know UNO has 1 i/o serial port, and Sparkfun's OBDII board doesn't work on same i/o serial port (at least i couldn't be able to), with uno when you send a command through serial to obd board you need to wait minimum 3 seconds to send another command or car's can-bus thinks that you canceled the first command returns STOPPED error, but with MEGA it works perfectly because mega has 3 i/o serial ports. You simply define Serial(TX)-Serial1(RX) and it works perfectly with 75ms delay.

Here is the working code.

```
//Set up ring buffer
char rxData[20];
char rxIndex = 0;
int rpmstored = 0;

    void setup()
    {
      Serial.begin(9600); // prints to serial monitor
      Serial1.begin(9600); //Hardware serial connection to the obdii uart
      OBD_init(); //initiates obd link
      delay(3000);
    }
   
    void loop()
{   
rpmstored = getRPM();
//int mph = (int)((getSPEED() * 10000L + 5) / 16090); //convert to mph
//  Serial.print (mph);
Serial.print("S:");
Serial.print (getSPEED());
Serial.print (",");
Serial.print("R:");
Serial.println (getRPM());
//Serial.print (",");
//Serial.print("W:");
//Serial.print (getWATERTEMP());
//Serial.print (",");
//Serial.print("O:");
//Serial.print (getOILTEMP());
//Serial.print (",");
//Serial.print("F:");
//Serial.print (getFUEL());
//Serial.print (",");
//Serial.print("V:");
//Serial.println (getVOLT());
delay(100);
Serial.flush();
    }
   
    void OBD_init(void)
    {
      //Wait for a little while before sending the reset command to the OBD-II-UART
      delay(2000);
      //Reset the OBD-II-UART
      Serial1.print("ATZ\r");
      //Wait for a bit before starting to send commands after the reset.
      delay(2);
      OBD_read();
      Serial1.print("ATE0\r");
      OBD_read();
      //Serial1.flush();
    }
   
    int getRPM(void)
    {
      //Query the OBD-II-UART for the Vehicle rpm
      Serial1.flush();
      Serial1.print("010C\r");
      OBD_read();

      return ((strtol(&rxData[6], 0, 16) * 256) + strtol(&rxData[9], 0, 16)) / 4;
    }

    int getSPEED(void)
    {
      //Query the OBD-II-UART for the vehicle speed
      Serial1.flush();
      Serial1.print("010D\r");
      OBD_read();

      return strtol(&rxData[6], 0, 16);
    }

    int getOILTEMP(void)
    {
      //Query the OBD-II-UART for the vehicle speed
      Serial1.flush();
      Serial1.print("015C\r");
      OBD_read();

      return strtol(&rxData[6], 0, 16);
    }

    int getFUEL(void)
    {
      //Query the OBD-II-UART for the vehicle speed
      Serial1.flush();
      Serial1.print("012F\r");
      OBD_read();

      return strtol(&rxData[6], 0, 16);
    }

    int getVOLT(void)
    {
      //Query the OBD-II-UART for the vehicle speed
      Serial1.flush();
      Serial1.print("0142\r");
      OBD_read();

      return strtol(&rxData[6], 0, 16);
    }

    int getWATERTEMP(void)
    {
      //Query the OBD-II-UART for the Engine Coolant Temp
      Serial1.flush();
      Serial1.print("0105\r");
      OBD_read();

      return strtol(&rxData[6], 0, 16) - 40;
    }
   
   
    void OBD_read(void)
    {
      char c;
      do {
        if (Serial1.available() > 0)
        {
          c = Serial1.read();
          if ((c != '>') && (c != '\r') && (c != '\n')) //Keep these out of our buffer
          {
            rxData[rxIndex++] = c; //Add whatever we receive to the buffer
          }
        }
      } while (c != '>'); //The ELM327 ends its response with this char so when we get it we exit out.
      rxData[rxIndex++] = '\0';//Converts the array into a string
      rxIndex = 0; //Set this to 0 so next time we call the read we get a "clean buffer"
   
    }
```

I only need RPM & Speed that's why i comnented out other parameters but tested all and works perfectly.